# Vim for Word (or something like it)

Tags: vim, editor

Are there any rich-text editors that have Vi(m) keybindings? Specifically, something like Word where I can compose a document with colors, headings, et al. but use Vi(m) bindings to move around and compose?

Answer (score 30):

So if you have to use MS Word and want vim key bindings, there is an [add on](http://www.viemu.com/viemu-vi-vim-word-outlook.html), but if you are not bound to that I would def. go for LaTeX + the [vim latex suite.](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: In addition, you can write in LaTeX and then use Pandoc (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert to Word (or many other formats).

Comment: Note that the ViEmu/Word & Outlook plugin is Windows only and does not say whether it is compatible with Word or Office beyond 2007. And (please correct me if I'm wrong) LaTex is not a rich-text editing environment, but instead is plain-text markup that compiles to rich text documents.

Comment: This would be awesome to have, VIM plugins and commands available in Word. VIM is a text editor. Even with the plugin mentioned below, it cant handle graphics, charts, images. Perhaps latex can, but you have to compile it etc before you can see it. Also word IMO is muc heasier to use compared to Latex, and I use it as a compilation of notes, access it from the cloud through onedrive. I use VIM intensively for programming, its amazing. But it cant do what Word can. Similarly Word cant do what VIM can.

Comment: It would be awesome to have something like the plugin that simulate VIM for VScode.

Comment: I've just installed the ViEmu plugin for Word (Office 365) and am blown away. Haven't extensively tested it, but everything looks awesome so far (except for the price.)

Comment: @KitJohnson Three years later and it still works with the latest version of Office. I am blown away too! Also, it is free of charge now. The author plans to open source it and meanwhile sends the license key for free per email on demand, see here: http://www.viemu.com/store.html

Answer (score 13):

Are you familiar with [Latex](http://www.latex-project.org/intro.html)?

Simply put it allows you to format your documents in plain text using tags or commands.

You then "compile" your document into the final format .pdf,.ps, etc.

Ex:

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \title{Cartesian closed categories and the price of eggs}
   \author{Jane Doe}
   \date{September 1994}
   \begin{document}
       \maketitle
         Hello world!
   \end{document}
```

This will allow you to write in vim, but still get professional non plain text output for your documents.

Comment: LaTeX, although very useful, is not a replacement for word. they have different paradigms and are useful in different contexts. LaTeX offers more beautiful text which can be used to print an actual published book, but word offers the kind of control LaTeX does not.

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to use vim for text editing, but want to, for example have text in different colors, bold it and such ... you can use [Txtfmt](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208) plugin. It enables you, by using special characters, to "prettify" plain text files a little. They can look quite nice, and it comes handy if you're used to vim, and are, for example, writing documentation for your programs which you'll later just get in word, and make an adjustment or two, and ship off.

Answer (score 5):

If you like Markdown or Latex, you could use the free open source Rstudio editor, with VIM-mode enabled. Export as either Word, PDF, or HTML etc.

Download Rstudio:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/RStudio/#Desktop

Read about markdown:

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 5):

If you want to (or have to) stay with Word and don't want to shell out $100 for a ViEmu license, you can try using [this AutoHotKey script](https://github.com/rcmdnk/vim_ahk) for providing some basic vi-like functionality. The repo linked also provides a standalone exe to get the same without using AutoHotKey.

There are many good reasons to ditch word entirely, but sometimes that's just not an option :(

Comment: Yes, all government organizations that I have worked for force you to use MS Office. 
That still doesn't stop me from continuing to use markdown and point my documentation to GitHub. Management tires of it, but oh well. I just can't stand Word.

Answer (score 4):

The Txtfmt plugin definitely provides the functionality you are looking for. It's a bit like having "rich text" capability for plain text in Vim.

[Txtfmt (The Vim Highlighter)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208)

[Screenshots](http://txtfmt.webs.com)

The latest version supports 8 configurable foreground and background colors, as well as all combinations of bold, underline, italic, etc... The highlighting is token-based, but the tokens are rendered invisible by the syntax, and can be inserted with very convenient and intuitive mappings, which don't require you to remember anything: e.g., "bold-underline" could be specified with a string such as *bu* or *ub*. The version under development even supports visual maps, which will permit you to select some text and say (for example) "Make this text red, bold-italic", and have the plugin handle insertion/removal of the appropriate tokens automatically. (It's really quite simple and intuitive, however, even with the non-visual mappings.)

Although the plugin is highly configurable, the default settings are appropriate for most users, and the author is more than happy to answer any setup or usage questions...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the text editor of your choice with vim keys (vim, emacs, sublime, atom, vscode ,etc.) and write your document in markdown. Then use an open source tool called [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) to translate it into almost any other markup language that you want. It is possible to compile your document to rich text formats including MS Word or even MS Powerpoint.
You can costumize your output by using a template.

Pandoc has extensive documentation and uses a richer markup syntax that allows you to do pretty much anything you want with the text. It is being actively developed by the community. Almost any major text editor has a few plugins for pandoc too.

Comment: This question is expressly off-topic (tool/product recommendation). Notice that it was asked in 2009, when the rules and guidelines were *very* different. And proposing a product, as you did, ends up looking like spam.

Answer (score 3):

There's a way of configuring [Abiword](http://www.abisource.com/) to use [vi key bindings](http://www.abisource.com/wiki/FaqEditorBindings)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GlobalVim](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9PDQ9H0CVLMS).
It can simulate vim modes and commands in most editing area.